# Blazor: Unable to resolve service for type xx while attempting to activate yyy

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor

I have read many other SO questions on the same topic, but none of the answers that I found applies to my case.

I have successfully added 4 services in my Startup.cs, and it was working fine before. I then added the 5th, and now I realize that something is broken - none of the services work. Even if I remove the 5th completely, the other ones are now also broken with the same error.

> Unable to resolve service for type xx while attempting to activate

This is my Startup.cs ConfigureServices.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddStorage();
    services.AddSingleton<IMyLocalStorage, MyLocalStorage>();
    services.AddSingleton<IFrontEndService, FrontEndService>();
    services.AddSingleton<ISystemProvider, SystemProviderService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
}
```

It's the last AuthenticationService that I noticed the error, but even the older previously working services fails now.

```
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
   // ... 
}

public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly FrontEndService frontEndService;
    private readonly MyLocalStorage myLocalStorage;

    public AuthenticationService(FrontEndService frontEndService, MyLocalStorage myLocalStorage)
    {
        this.frontEndService = frontEndService;
        this.myLocalStorage = myLocalStorage;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The services are simple; one interface, one implementation of that interface, and then adding in Startup.cs. I can't figure out why it stopped working.

So if I remove IAuthenticationService, then the error instead shows up in FrontEndService, then complaining on the MyLocalStorage:

```
public interface IFrontEndService
{
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string requestUri);
}

public class FrontEndService : IFrontEndService
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;
    private readonly MyLocalStorage myLocalStorage;

    public FrontEndService(HttpClient client, MyLocalStorage myLocalStorage)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyLocalStorage : IMyLocalStorage
{
    public MyLocalStorage(LocalStorage storage)
    {
        this.storage = storage;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call methods on `IServiceCollection` such as `.AddSingleton<IFrontEndService, FrontEndService>()`, you're saying to the container, "Whenever you see an `IFrontEndService` dependency, inject an instance of `FrontEndService`." Now if you take a look at your `AuthenticationService`:

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly FrontEndService frontEndService;
    private readonly MyLocalStorage myLocalStorage;

    public AuthenticationService(FrontEndService frontEndService, MyLocalStorage myLocalStorage)
    {
        this.frontEndService = frontEndService;
        this.myLocalStorage = myLocalStorage;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Notice how you're passing in dependencies of `FrontEndService` and `MyLocalStorage`, rather than the interfaces you registered. That means the container doesn't recognise them, so it doesn't know how to fulfil the dependency graph.

You need to change the service to depend on the interfaces, as those are what you've registered with the container:

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly IFrontEndService frontEndService;
    private readonly IMyLocalStorage myLocalStorage;

    public AuthenticationService(IFrontEndService frontEndService, IMyLocalStorage myLocalStorage)
    {
        this.frontEndService = frontEndService;
        this.myLocalStorage = myLocalStorage;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thats odd, cause I have used exactly this approach before, and it worked fine. If you read the docs, Microsoft also uses the concrete class, not the interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#dependency-injection-in-services

Are you sure? =)

Comment: @Ted If you take a closer look at those docs, you'll see they are using the interfaces: `@inject IDataAccess DataRepository`. Same for `ComponentBase`, where property injection is used via the `[Inject]` attribute. If you're talking about the use of `HttpClient` as a dependency, this is a type that is already registered for you, hence why it can be injected.

Comment: Really, cause this is what they write for injecting into services: _"Complex services might require additional services. In the prior example, DataAccess might require the HttpClient default service. @inject (or the InjectAttribute) isn't available for use in services. Constructor injection must be used instead. Required services are added by adding parameters to the service's constructor."_ So, they are _not_ using `inject`, right?

Comment: Please note that I am building a service, where _inject_ is not available.

Comment: @Ted _Constructor injection must be used instead._ which is what will happen for you if you use the interfaces you've registered. To be clear, there are single typed versions of `.AddX()` methods, where you can just specify a concrete type instead of an interface/concrete type pair, and that will inject an instance of the concrete type. Both will work, as long as you're matching up the registered types with those you actually inject.

Comment: But u said that the docs "are using the interfaces". They are not. The `@inject IDataAccess DataRepository` is in a _component_, not a service. Same thing with ComponentBase, its not in a service. So... something doesnt add up. I have used the concrete classes before, some 2-3 days ago in this same project, and it worked fine. Now when I return, it doesnt work. I will try the interface-approach, but that still doesnt explain why it worked before and why MS themselves say "usin concrete class".

Comment: I changed to the Interfaces, but then the webpage froze and was unresponsive, until Chome asked if I wanted to close it.

Comment: @Ted: _"Microsoft also uses the concrete class"_ that is quite possible but then also Register those concrete classes. DI will do both, just be consistent.

Comment: So, awarded the answer here, as you were first. This doesnt explain why it worked up until now... hmm. @HenkHolterman But the comments above, that "they are using interfaces" doesnt apply here, as thise Inject stuff is in Component, not services =)

Answer (score 1):

@Ted, 
Do you remember a question of yours from a couple of weeks ago, in which you used LocalStorage in a service ? At that service you had a constructor with IStorage parameter, but this caused an error, the reason of which was that though the LocalStorage class implements the IStorage interface, the creators of this library added the LocalStorage to the DI container as a concrete class like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddStorage(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            return services.AddSingleton<SessionStorage>()
                .AddSingleton<LocalStorage>();
        }
```

And therefore, you had to use

> (LocalStorage storage)

instead of

> (IStorage storage)

The extension method above, could be rewritten thus:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddStorage(this IServiceCollection services)
            {
                return services.AddSingleton<IStorage, SessionStorage>()
                    .AddSingleton<IStorage, LocalStorage>();
            }
```

In which case, you could use the IStorage interface in your constructor.

Now you may form a general rule, and act accordingly.

Ted says:

> Thats odd, cause I have used exactly this approach before, and it
>   worked fine. If you read the docs, Microsoft also uses the concrete
>   class, not the interface

HttpClient derives from HttpMessageInvoker. It does not implement any interface.

This code-snippet shows how the HttpClient is added to the service container, and made available for injection in your client-side Blazor:

```
services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(s =>
        {
            // Creating the URI helper needs to wait until the JS Runtime is initialized, so defer it.
            var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<IUriHelper>();
            return new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(WebAssemblyUriHelper.Instance.GetBaseUri())
            };
        });
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, what puzzles me is that I do use the `AddSingleton<ISomething, Something>` in my Startup.cs, and that has worked up until just now - I promise! The application was running fine, and I was using the concrete classes even with the above method call in Startup.cs. This is what really confuses me. Hmm....

Comment: The solution u describe is correct, but I awarded the answer to JohnH as he was actually first. Still, confused as how it worked just a few days ago. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm confused too, as adding a singleton service of the type specified in TService with an implementation type specified in TImplementation to the DI Container requires you to use the abstraction (interface) when you inject the TService in Components or when using constructor injection. Note that the abstraction is referred to as the  service, not the concrete class. If it previously worked for you, but not now, may be attributed to a variety of causes, including bugs, etc.   Testing is essential here...

Comment: Yeah, something happened, because I am 100% sure that it worked before, when using the Interface-approach and injecting with concrete classes. Im wondering if Win10 did some update and with it came some, ehm, .NET update or something, that changed the behaviour? Sounds a bit far fetched though... hehe.